# Adobe Catalyst - 'Attribute Price' adding on to 'Sell Price' Issue

Tags: adobe, business-catalyst

I have set a products sell price at £100. I have also created a 'Size' attribute at 'Large' £120.

But when I view the product and select 'Large' it prices up at £220 (adding the attribute and sell price together) when I'm wanting it at just the £120.

Any thoughts on why I'm getting this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I believe Daut maybe talking about something else but I could be wrong.

When using attributes that you talk about, the price is calculated by default price plus the attribute price. This is why you see £220 as your total, as you have figured out.

In other words, your default price is £100. For your total to be £120, then your `Large` attribute would actually be £20. When it adds together, your total price will be £120.

When I use attributes with varying cost, I typically write my attribute as:

Large + [then BC inserts the price.]

On the BC App Store, there are a couple plugins ([here](http://www.bcappstore.com/apps/dynamic-price) and [here](http://www.bcappstore.com/apps/attributes-plus)) that assist with using Attributes. Their main purpose, from my understanding, is controling how the information is displayed to customers. I have no experience using either of these but it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Hi have created my own way around this issue in BC I also shared it on Business Catalyst Forum too. for select dropdown or radio buttons use the code bellow, you need to have a certain code ability to mend it together, it was quite done some time ago but if somebody interested on improving it to a cleaner way be welcome to share.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


StartDynamicPrice();
DoPriceChange();
});
var el_totalprice='#totalprice';
    var el_totalprice_gst='#totalprice_gst';
    //var el_attrselect='.catProdAttributeItem select';
    // uncomment if you want radio as well
    var el_attrselect='.catProdAttributeItem select, .catProdAttributeItem input';
    var currencysymbol='£';

    Number.prototype.toMoney=function(decimals, decimal_sep, thousands_sep){
       var n = this,
       c = isNaN(decimals) ? 2 : Math.abs(decimals),
       d = decimal_sep || '.',
       t = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
       sign = (n < 0) ? '-' : '',
       i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(n).toFixed(c)) + '',
       j = ((j = i.length) > 3) ? j % 3 : 0;
       return sign + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : '') + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : '');
    }

    DoPriceChange=function(){
        var selected='';
        var newsubtotal=0;
        $.each($(el_attrselect), function(i,e){
            selected=$(e).children(':selected').text();
            if (selected.indexOf(currencysymbol) != -1){
                newsubtotal+=parseFloat(selected.substring(selected.indexOf(currencysymbol)+1));
            };
        });
        newtotal=parseFloat($(el_totalprice).attr('base'))+parseFloat(newsubtotal);
        newtotal_gst=newtotal+(newtotal*.10);
        $(el_totalprice).html(currencysymbol+newtotal.toMoney());
        $(el_totalprice_gst).html(currencysymbol+newtotal_gst.toMoney());
    }

    StartDynamicPrice=function(){
        $(el_totalprice).attr('base',$(el_totalprice).html().replace(currencysymbol,'').replace(' ,',''));       // set base price
        $(el_attrselect).on('change',function(){
            DoPriceChange();
        })
    }
/// END
```

Answer (score 0):

Attributes in BC are add-ons. You cannot just get the attribute.
What you need is product grouping.

Group products together

You can create multiple products of the same type and group them together. A customer viewing one product can also see the available variations by selecting another product from the group.

Check how Grouping works in Business Catalyst

From the Actions menu, select Group Products Together.

Move the products from the left panel to the right, select a default product, and click Save.

Note: The default product is the only product that displays in a catalog. All other grouped products are available through the grouped product drop-down menu.